# How to exclude subfolders containing "[xxx] - ( yy) - [xxx]"

Tags: bash, parsing, directory, subdirectory

I have folders organized like this:

```
Folder1
[xxx] - ( aa) - [xxx]
 1.zip
 2.zip
Folder2
[xxx] - ( bb ) - [xxx]
 11.zip
 22.zip
```

I need to:

- go into every Folderx unzip the files it contains
- log if the extracted file was not successfully extracted
- move the extracted file to another folder
- log if the extracted file was not successfully moved
  I don't want the process if anything fails.

I came up with that at the begining:

```
for D in `find . -type d`
do
    cd $D
    echo "$(pwd)"
    for z in *.zip; do
        unzip -u $z
        echo "File: " $z; 
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            then
                echo "Successfully created file"
            else
                echo "Could not create file" >&2
        fi; 
    done
done
```

I tried many things like replacing "find . -maxdepth 1 -type d" by "find . -maxdepth 1" or use arrays etc but there's always something which fails.

My main problem, I think is that when I try:

```
$ find . -type d
```

I get this result:

```
Folder1
Folder1/[xxx] - ( aa) - [xxx]
Folder2
Folder2/[xxx] - ( bb ) - [xxx]
```

But when I use the same command in my scripts it parses it like this instead:

```
Folder1
[xxx]
-
( 
a
)
-
[xxx]
Folder2
[xxx]
-
(
bb
)
-
[xxx]
```

I have never found a way of avoiding splitting the path at every space...

Any hints please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the poor layout, I guess I'm pretty bad at using this here...

Comment: Thanks, I gave it another shot and it's better I guess... Quoting doesn't work very well... Or at least i'm not using as it's supposed to be here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your directories contain whitespaces, word splitting is performed on them (in each line `find` returns). See a nice explanation of this very scenario (`for` loop over list of files) on the [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) page.

One of the ways to write your outermost `for` loop is like this:

```
find . -type d | while read D; do
    cd "$D"
    ...
done
```

Another approach, for simpler actions, is to just use `find` with `-execdir` action, like this:

```
find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -u '{}' \;
```

Note we use `execdir` action which executes the command *in the file directory*, and not `exec` which executes the command in the current directory, because `unzip` extracts in the current dir, unless given the destination dir thru `-d` option.

Or in bash 4+, you can use the glob recursive expansion:

```
shopt -s globstar
for z in ./**/*.zip; do
    dir="$(dirname "$z")"
    cd "$dir"
    unzip -u "$z" && echo "OK" || echo "Failed to extract $z"
done
```

Also, don't forget to (almost) **always quote your variables**.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, "find . -type d | while read D; do" has put me on the way, it's not working (although the script still lacks of several things.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue has now been solved thanks to randomir! thanks a lot!

This is what i've done so far:

```
BASE=/path/to/my/stuff

find . -type d | while read D
do
    EXTRACTED=0
    if [[ ! "$D" =~ ^(.*)"[" ]] && [[ ! "$D" =~ ^\.$ ]]
        then cd $BASE/$D
            for z in *.zip
            do
            unzip -u $z
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                    then
                        echo "ZIP SUCCESS - " $D"/"$z >> $BASE/details.log
                    else
                        echo "ZIP FAILED - " $D"/"$z >> $BASE/details.log
                        EXTRACTED=1
                fi; 
            done
        unrar x -o+ *.rar 
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            then
                echo "RAR SUCCESS - " $D >> $BASE/details.log
            else
                echo "RAR FAILED - " $D >> $BASE/details.log
                EXTRACTED=1
        fi; 

        if [ $EXTRACTED -eq 0 ]
            then
                echo "SUCCESS - " $D >> $BASE/main.log
            else
                echo "FAILED - " $D >> $BASE/main.log
        fi; 
    fi;
done
```

Comment: One of the other challanges I was facing was that the script would try to access to "." as well as the other subfolders and it took me a while to understand that it could easily be solved by assding this to my if "&& [[ ! "$D" =~ ^\.$ ]]" to manage that...

Comment: Try ``find . -mindepth 1 -type d`` instead. It'll return only subdirectories, skipping the ``.``.

Comment: And **please** [always quote your variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). For example, write: ``cd "$BASE/$D"``, ``unzip -u "$z"``, ``echo "Success - $D/$z"``.